# Using the [[clip_distance]] attribute in a Metal shader?

Tags: metal

In a Metal shader, I am trying to make use of the [[clip_distance]] attribute in the output structure of a vertex shader function as follows:

```
struct vtx_out
{
    float4 gl_Position [[position]];
    float gl_ClipDistance[1] [[clip_distance]];
};
```

However, this results in the following shader compilation error:

```
<program source>:86:32: error: 'clip_distance' attribute cannot be applied to types
    float gl_ClipDistance[1] [[clip_distance]];
                               ^
```

I am trying to compile this for running on a Mac running OS X El Capitan.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I make use of the [[clip_distance]] attribute?

Comment: This is orthogonal to the error you're getting, but how are you setting your user clip plane(s)?

Comment: @warrenm As a float4, either generated within the shader, or passed in as a uniform, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
struct vtx_out
{
  float4 gl_Position [[position]];
  float gl_ClipDistance [[clip_distance]] [1];
};
```

In the Metal shading language `clip_distance` is a declaration attribute.
The C++ spec `[dcl.array]` states:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
>
> ... The optional attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the array.

This is why placing the attribute at the end makes Clang treat it like a type attribute and you get the error that you see.